# if の箇所で expected declaration というエラーがでる

Tags: swift

１０回ボタンを押すとメッセージが表示されるプログラムを書こうとしたのですが、ifの部分でexpected declaration のエラーが発生します。どうすれば解決できるのかご教授ください。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var CountNum = 10

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        label.text = String(CountNum)
        CountNum--
    }
    if CountNum == 0 {//ここでエラーが出てくる
    label.text = "0になりました"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

手元でも確認しましたが、
Expected declarationのエラーが起きますね。

これは、クラス内部で直接処理を書いている為です。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var CountNum = 10

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        label.text = String(CountNum)
        CountNum--
    }
    // ここはクラス内部
    //if CountNum == 0 {
    //label.text = "0になりました"
    //}
}
```

そのため、エラーになるのです。
if文は、必ず関数内部に書きましょう。

１０回ボタンを押すとメッセージが表示されるプログラムの場合、

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var CountNum = 10

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        CountNum--
        if CountNum == 0 {
            label.text = "0になりました"
        }else{
            label.text = String(CountNum)
        }
    }
}
```

このようにすると良いと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます、実際に動作することが確認できました！

Comment: @purera もし問題が解決したのであれば、@Tetsunari Niinaさんの回答を承認して「花まるアンサー」のマークを付けてあげてください。詳細は[ツアー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)を見てください。